# Android. ImageView.setImageURI(myUri) 2 и более раз

Tags: java, android

Имеется ImageView:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

В коде нашли его:

```
...
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewPreview);
...
```

Далее:

```
imageView.setImageURI(myUri);
```

Отлично, в ImageView отобразилась картинка, но проблема в том, что мне в этой ImageView надо периодически менять изображения, вызвав второй раз

```
imageView.setImageURI(myUriTwo);
```

В ImageView остается старое изображение. Как поменять изображение в ImageView?

UPD: Важное замечание, в imageView методом setImageURI я передаю одинаковую ссылку, т.е. первый раз отображается изображение, если все норм, по нажатию кнопки изображение (jpg файл) видоизменяется, и необходимо отобразить измененное изображение. Вызываю метод второй раз, с тем же myUri(а не myUriTwo), jpg изображение на носителе перезаписалось, а ImageView остается прежний.

Решил проблему так:

```
imageView.setImageResource(0);
imageView.setImageURI(myUri);
```

Вероятнее всего изображение просто кешируется, но мое решение проблемы больше похоже на костыль. Есть идеи? Или оставить так будет вполне нормально (P.S. учусь писать правильно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всё правильно делаете. Если заглянуть в [исходники](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29) сего метода:

```
public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
     if (mResource != 0 ||
             (mUri != uri &&
              (uri == null || mUri == null || !uri.equals(mUri)))) {
         updateDrawable(null);
         mResource = 0;
         mUri = uri;

         final int oldWidth = mDrawableWidth;
         final int oldHeight = mDrawableHeight;

         resolveUri();

         if (oldWidth != mDrawableWidth || oldHeight != mDrawableHeight) {
             requestLayout();
         }
         invalidate();
     }
 }
```

то видно, что виджет перерисовывается только если URI, ранее назначенное, не `null`, не идентично переданному и/или не назначалось вовсе.

Т.к. вы передаёте тот же самый экземпляр URI, то условие не выполняется и изображение не меняется. Так что да - надо сначала обнулить внутренний URI у `ImageView` и только потом назначать его заново.